# SSH Putty Connection Timeout Issue

Tags: ssh, apache-2.4, centos6

Hi I am getting a really annoying SSH Putty Connection Timeout Issue
which I can not fix

Happens when its running a command which is taking a while - some of the commands I run can take 2 hours or more to complete When it disconnects I can not see if the command completed or not.

I have a dedicated server centos 6 , 16gb ram - Apache 2.4 and Nginx PHP 5.6 and PHP 7.1 using with MultiPHP Manager PHP-FM - I have tried to increase some settings via WHM but not making any difference - can someone let me know which settings I should be looking to increase or change to fix this problem

Comment: i think running the command in background mode will solve that, you can do that by adding the & symbol to the end of the command

Comment: Network Error Caused Connection Abort is what happens after it runs over 2 hours  I will try the suggestion and update

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as if changing the `tcp_keepalive_time` kernel keepalive setting may help.

Check the value (usually set to 7200 seconds) thus:

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
```

and to increase the value do:

```
   echo 14400 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_keepalive_time
```

Comment: This looks more like it as I did get 7200 when checking and it happens after 2 hours, I increased it as per your suggestion and will update thanks

Comment: I have tried the suggestion in the Answer however I see that now still the putty is getting disconnected and becomes un-useable fails to complete the task in the command - but only now there is not error display popup coming as before

Comment: You need a much, much lower number here, say 300.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest using Linux `screen` sessions, they are made to solve this problem.

you basically

- create a screen session and run your program
- detach from the session if you don't need it, and even if you ssh connection breaks the screen session is still running
- when you ssh back to the server you reattach to the screen session and find you results.

here is [a link to a simple tutorial about screens.](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-use-linux-screen/)